# Linq to Entities & SQL Server 2012: Insert consecutive number by a combination of fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm using:

Linq to entities and SQL Server 2012.

I need to insert consecutive numbers into a table. The numbers need to be consecutive for a combination of other fields in the table.

This is the (simplified) table structure:

```
Id: uniqueidentifier
ShiftId: uniqueidentifier (NULL)
Number: bigint <-- This should be consecutive per shift 
                   or consecutive when ShiftId is null
```

I cannot have "jumps"in the consecutive value.

I was evaluating using ROW_NUMBER, sequences, identities but nothing looks quite right specially to be used with linq to entities.

What is the best way to do this? If it is not possible to do it just with linq to entities, what is the best way to do it inside a stored procedure, trigger, etc.?

**EDIT: To add more details**:
The application handles many accounts. On each account the day is divided into Shifts. During that shift all orders created need to have a consecutive number, starting with one. When the shift is closed the next order (for the next shift) will have number 1 and everything starts again.

When a new order is created my process should find the max order number for the current account and shift, increase it by one and use it for the order.

Comment: I'd do this in a database trigger. Sequences (the new ones in SS2012) can't do this. BTW, what if a record is deleted?

Comment: @Gert: The application does not allow to delete these records. The users can set the records to "inactive". Can you post an answer with your ideas about the trigger?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not inserting the records all at once, in a sequence? You just want to increase the number every time a record is inserted?

Comment: @Floremin: The users are creating orders, one at a time. Each order needs to have a consecutive number during the current shift. When the shift changes, the number starts with 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that if you can add a `DateTime` field you could create a view that automatically creates this "Number" field for you.

```
SELECT Id, 
ShiftId, 
DateTimeField, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ShiftId ORDER BY DateTimeField) AS Number
```

For each ShiftId, the earliest DateTime field would number get number 1 and increment without any gaps.  Would this work in your situation?

Comment: My concern with this type of solution is a concurrency problem. There is going to be a small amount of time between reading the next number and actually saving the record. With several users working at the same time there is a chance of two users getting the same number.